# Best way to use MySQLi inside a class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

Currently I'm doing this:

```
function __construct( $mysqli_connection )
{
    if( ! empty($mysqli_connection) && is_object($mysqli_connection) && ! $mysqli_connection->connect_error )
    {
        //Make the $mysqli universal to the class equal the given connection
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli_connection;
    }
    else
    {
        die("An invalid MySQLi connection was given.\n");
    }

}//function __construct
```

And the initiating the class with:

```
new className( $mysqli );
```

It works fine, however it seems to me that:

- That extra code is unnecessary
- The memory used to occupy a MySQLi resource ends up doubled (one is in the class' memory, but there still is one in the main code)

Are my above points true, and if so, is there a better way to use a MySQLi resource from inside a class? The above method is the only way I've found from searching.

Comment: Create a database wrapper (or use an existing one) and pass that around rather than the raw mysqli connection. Benefits being that you can change the driver at any point (depending on the interface) without having to change all of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code can be reduced to:

```
private $mysqli;

function __construct(mysqli $conn)
{
    $this->mysqli = $conn;
}
```

Your class shouldn't have to worry about whether the connection was established, it should be able to assume that it is. Also, type hints help to indicate what class is expected when the constructor is called.

Second, the `mysqli` object is not duplicated when you're using it inside another object; instead, its reference count is increased. Once the count drops to zero the object gets removed. If an object was always copied, doing dependency injection would become very expensive.

Comment: Can also note that this is an implementation of the dependency injection design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It surprises me that this is the case - because something like `function __construct($int){ $this->integer = $int; }` would store a second copy of the integer. Can you please explain / point me to something explaining how an object is any different? Thanks